# How to "bind only once" in angular2+ templates

Tags: angular, angular-template

I need to set a `data-target` attribute on a `div` based on the component `number`.

```
<div [attr.data-target]="'target-'+number">
```

I want the `data-target` to be set only one time and do not change if the value of `number` is modified later (that is not the case here because of the `[]` binding).

How could I achieve this ?

*Background: in my case the `data-target` is used by an external library not included in my Angular's app that is why I do not want it to be modified otherwise this would break the current page.*

*PS: there is an obvious solution that consists in creating a variable initialNumber that stores that value but I would like to avoid adding such logic in my component.*

Comment: you can use two variables, one is changed once, which will binded to data-target

Comment: Is this what you are maybe looking for https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy
If it is not, then you can only manually track changes and reset the value. This feature existed in Angular1, but it is no longer there.

Comment: You could force `number` to keep the first value that is assigned to it (unless it is used for something else and needs to be updated). It would be similar to the "obvious solution" that you mention in your question.

Comment: well you are using a dynamic field to modify a static value. So i think the solution is rather obvious (your P.S.)